# Is there any API to get list of devices in LAN

Tags: android, android-networking

i wanna get the list of devices that are in LAN. Is there any API to get such information. For now, i have JAVA code like this.

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet){
   int timeout=1000;
   for (int i=1;i<254;i++){
       String host=subnet + "." + i;
       if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
           System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
       }
   }
}
```

But i wanna use android API if available. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jmdns.sourceforge.net

You can create a service and discover service on LAN.